# UIImage Frame Null in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I am trying to display star rating images, and I have three star images: full star, half star and an unselected grey-ed out star.

I have an array which holds the stars: so for rating 4.5, it would hold 4 selected and 1 half. I am adding the same star objects into the array so that I do not have to create multiple instances of the stars. I have just three instances and in my calculations I am just using `addObject` on those three different images as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ratingCount; i++) {
        if (rating >= 1)
            [self.imageViews addObject:self.selected];
        else
            [self.imageViews addObject:self.halfSelected];
        rating--;
}
```

I am having an issue drawing these images. In a subsequent loop, I am trying to draw them out as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.imageViews.count; ++i) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(i * (5 + imageWidth), 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
```

This crashes because `imageView.frame` is coming out as null. When I debugged it, it prints out null `<0x00000000>`. Why is the frame coming out as null? The images are not printing as null and I know that they are added to the array properly.

When removing imageView.frame, I also get an `[UIImage superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8644590`

The images are instantiated using `imageNamed` in the `init` method. Would that cause an issue? Do they get allocated early? That should print null when trying to see the image in the debugger using `po` so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: i have a great tutorial of start rating display can i post as a answer?

Comment: I saw it and what I have is very similar to what they did.

Comment: **Hope this link will charm you.** [Click here.](https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating/tree/master/DLStarRating)

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial of ray wenderlich http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a `UIImage` with a `UIImageView`. Your array contains images, which do not have frames, since they are not views.

You need a separate set of image views, which have the images assigned to them.